# Which Catalog I will buy Pantone Solid or Color Bridge?

Tags: color, print-design, cmyk, pantone

What is the difference PANTONE 340 U and PANTONE 340 UP? Is the UP color CMYK process printed color or not? Because they are really different. I want to buy pantone catalog today and I don't know Color Bridge is enough for me? For example I am generally using Pantone 320 C and this color is our company branding color. If I send something to print I am using Pantone 320C, If I sent something to print as CMYK, I am using 100,0,31,5 CMYK. So Color Bridge is enough for me? What is including this cartela?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend getting a Color Bridge set that includes both C and U. Each Color Bridge will contain a solid swatch next to its process analog, so you get everything in two guides.

Comment: *That is, everything but some specialty libraries that don't generally have process analogs, like metallics, hexachromes, etc.

Comment: I bought Color Bridge today. So this first square is showing how special pantone solid color will seem on paper and right side square is showing CMYK process color? If it's right I bought right and perfect one. But difference is very big between special solid color and CMYK process color.

Comment: Yes. It's easier to see with a loupe, but the left is generally the solid ink, while the right is PANTONE's official CMYK formula. Some colors are much closer than others. The colors that are farther off are due to pigments mixed into the ink that fall outside of the CMYK gamut, like fluorescent colors. It should be noted that many modern printers, like the HP Indigo series and some 6-ink printers, can come closer to the solid swatch than the guide may indicate.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the most recent *Pantone Colour Suffix Differences* from the PANTONE *Help Center*:

> > CV = computer video. This designation is used to denote that a color is an electronic simulation of a PANTONE Color. It is used in older versions of software applications that license PANTONE Colors, e.g., Adobe Illustrator, Macromedia FreeHand, QuarkXPress, Adobe Photoshop, etc.
> >     CVC = computer video, coated paper. This denotes electronic simulation of the color specifically as it appears on coated paper; "CVU" does the same on uncoated paper.
> >     C = coated paper, i.e., PANTONE 185 C
> >     U = uncoated paper, i.e., PANTONE 185 U
> >     CP = coated paper, process simulation, i.e., PANTONE 185 CP (used in PANTONE+ COLOR BRIDGE COATED).
> >     UP = uncoated paper, process simulation, i.e., PANTONE 185 UP (used in PANTONE+ COLOR BRIDGE UNCOATED).
> >     The following designations for PANTONE Colors used in earlier versions of PANTONE COLOR BRIDGE *are now obsolete*:
> >     PC = process simulation, coated paper, i.e., PANTONE 185 PC. 
> >     UP= uncoated paper, process simulation, i.e., PANTONE 185 UP. 
> >     EC - Euro process simulation, coated paper, i.e., PANTONE 185 EC. This was used in the European version which is now obsolete.